# multitouch and buttons in same view

Tags: objective-c, ios, button, multi-touch

hi I have an app UIViewController that supports multitouch and has some buttons too, what i need is that when user double click on button it opens a new view, and when the user move is finger on screen it opens other view.

The app works fine if user put his finger in the area where there is no button, but if he puts his fingers in the area where there are buttons nothing happens

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
 button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
            [button addTarget:self 
                       action:@selector(openPic:)
             forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDownRepeat];
            button.tag = image;
            button.frame = CGRectMake(orInc, inc,  70.0, 95.0);
            [self.view addSubview:button];
]


-(void) openPic:(id)sender  {
    UINavigationController *nav=[[UINavigationController alloc]init];
    PicController *x=[[PicController alloc]init];
    nav.viewControllers=[NSArray arrayWithObject:x];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:x animated:YES];
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UINavigationController *nav=[[UINavigationController alloc]init];
    ViewController *x=[[ViewController alloc]init];
    nav.viewControllers=[NSArray arrayWithObject:x];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:x animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `userInteractionEnabled` property of he UIButton object to `NO` and try it.

Comment: thanks for answering, if I set userInteractionEnabled to NO button do not work anymore, what I need is that if users double click button openPic gets called, If user just touches screen even over button touchesEnded gets called